# How to find the maximum number of words in a pandas dataframe column of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of strings. I am trying to find (a) maximum number of words in the column and (b) the row that contains the string with the maximum number of words.

I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

something = ["Hello how are you", "I am doing great", "Lets go camping"]

test = pd.DataFrame(something)
test.columns = ["Response"]

length_of_the_messages = test["Response"].str.split("\\s+")
print(length_of_the_messages)
print(length_of_the_messages.len().max())
```

But this generates an error saying `Series` does have no attribute `len`. How can I can I get both maximum number of words in a string in the column and its row index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.str` and for index `.idxmax`:

```py
import pandas as pd

something = ["Hello how are you", "I am doing great", "Lets go camping"]

test = pd.DataFrame(something)
test.columns = ["Response"]

length_of_the_messages = test["Response"].str.split("\\s+")

print(length_of_the_messages)
print("Max number of words = ", length_of_the_messages.str.len().max())
print("Index = ", length_of_the_messages.str.len().idxmax())
```

Prints:

```
0    [Hello, how, are, you]
1     [I, am, doing, great]
2       [Lets, go, camping]
Name: Response, dtype: object

Max number of words =  4
Index =  0
```

Comment: Kinda wierd that .str.len() works on a Series of lists. ... Pretty tricky - it is in the docs - `The element may be a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or a collection (such as a dictionary).`

Comment: @wwii `.str` is kind of *universal* - it just "passes" the function to the cell. So you can have column of `sets` and `.str.len()` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by creating a column of word counts, sorting by counts via `sort_values()`, and retrieving the first row:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
import pandas as pd

table_str = '''Sentence
Hello how are you
I am doing great
Lets go camping
'''

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(table_str), header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
    df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(" ").map(len))
    df = df.sort_values(['Count'], ascending=False)
    print(df.iloc[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ ./67927014.py
Sentence    Hello how are you
Count                       4
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the word count by `.str.len()` and get its max with `.max()`

As for the index of those entries with max length, as the Series has 2 rows with the max length, you can get a complete list of indice of max length, as follows:

```
something = ["Hello how are you", "I am doing great", "Lets go camping"]

test = pd.DataFrame(something)
test.columns = ["Response"]

length_of_the_messages = test["Response"].str.split("\\s+")

print(length_of_the_messages)
print("Max number of words = ", length_of_the_messages.str.len().max())
print("Index = ", length_of_the_messages.loc[length_of_the_messages.str.len() == length_of_the_messages.str.len().max()].index)
```

Output:

```
0    [Hello, how, are, you]
1     [I, am, doing, great]
2       [Lets, go, camping]
Name: Response, dtype: object
Max number of words =  4
Index =  Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Here, the 2 indexes of the same max length are printed as:

```
Index =  Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `idxmax` alone is enough and we can deduce the `max` from it with `loc`:

```
# we need `.str` accessor for `len`, too
idx_max = test.Response.str.split().str.len().idxmax()
val_max = test.Response.loc[idx_max].item()
```

to get

```
>>> idx_max
0

>>> val_max
"Hello how are you"
```